# Embedded Powerbi Edit and Create report, when trying to save throwing error

Tags: powerbi

I am working on integrating Power BI reports into our web application. The embedding works fine, we are using the save() and saveAs() in the js lib to save our reports but in the edit mode and create mode attempting saving, the below error is throwing.

> Something went wrong
>
> Unable to save the report
>
> Please verify you have the right permissions or contact support. If you contact support, please provide these details.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you generated the embed token with access to the report, the dataset, and the workspace where the dataset is located. If you want to save the report to another workspace, the token needs to have access to the target workspace. And make sure your application has the following scopes:

1. Report.ReadWrite.All
2. Workspaces.ReadWrite.All

You must also set the allowEdit : true flag for each report that customer needs to edit. For setting allowEdit to true you can use following JSON request body:

```
{
  "datasets": [
    {
      "id": // ID of the dataset
    }
  ],
  "reports": [
    {
      "allowEdit": true,
      "id": // ID of the report
    }
  ]
}
```

To contact support you can use the link, https://support.powerbi.com/ and provide the following information:

1. Activity ID
2. Request ID
3. Correlation ID
4. Time (When you are facing the issue)
5. Service version
6. Client version
7. Cluster URI

Please refer:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/create-edit-report-embed-view?tabs=embed-for-your-customers#required-access-token-permissions-for-saving
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/power-bi/embed-token/embed-token-generate-token#generate-embedtoken-for-a-dataset-and-two-reports.-editing-is-allowed-for-only-one-of-the-two-reports